# Ruby Splatted Array

Tags: ruby

Create a method called introduction that accepts a person's age, gender and any number of names, then returns a String that introduces that person by combining all of these values to create a message acceptable to the tests.

```
def introduction(age, gender, *names)
  "Meet #{names.join(' ')}, who's #{age} and #{gender}"
end
```

For the .join method. Why do I need to add a string with a space (' ')?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't take your orders.

Comment: There actually was a question after the orders though.  We've seen worse.

Comment: You don't need to. But that is an array, so it makes sense to print it using `join`.

Comment: @DavidGrayson You are right. But this post is bad enough.

Comment: @ekim: Did you try what happens if you don't add the string?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of Ruby's `Array#join` method can be found here:

http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join

The string `' '` is a string with a single space in it.  That string is supplied as the separator argument to `Array#join`.  If you left out that argument, then the names would not have any spaces between them, and it would look bad:

> Meet DavidGrayson, who's 123 and male.

But if you include the space, it should look like this:

> Meet David Grayson, who's 123 and male.

You should be able to answer a question like that yourself by running the code in IRB or some other Ruby environment and seeing how it behaves.  Experimentation is a great way to start understanding something.